# Python Multiprocessing calling object method

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing

I want to use Python's multiprocessing module to start a new process which creates some other object and calls that objects loops_forever method.

In my main class I have:

```
import OtherService
from multiprocessing import Process
my_other_service = OtherService(address=ADDRESS)
my_other_process = Process(target=my_other_service.loops_forever())
print("got here")
my_other_process.start()
print("done")
```

When I run this code, "got here" never gets printed. loops_forever gets called just above the "got here" print, and control never returns back to my main class.

What am I doing wrong here?
I have used multiprocessing before in this fashion:

```
my_other_process = Process(target=OtherService, kwargs={"address":ADDRESS})
my_other_process.start()
```

which correctly calls OtherService's init function and runs the init function as a separate process.
The only difference is this time I want to call init function AND then run the loops_forever method forever as a separate process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you do `target=my_other_service.loops_forever()`, you call `loops_forever`. To pass it as a function, rather than call it, you would drop the parentheses, like `target=my_other_service.loops_forever`.

Comment: Wow what a silly mistake. Thank you @pycoder