# Python: start new process that executes another object's method

Tags: python, subprocess, python-multiprocessing

I want to start a new process that will create some other object and then calls that objects loops_forever method.

I tried using Python's multiprocessing module as described in my previous SO question here: [Python Multiprocessing calling object method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47640541/python-multiprocessing-calling-object-method/47640580#47640580)

Here is what I tried:

```
import OtherService
from multiprocessing import Process
my_other_service = OtherService(address=ADDRESS)
my_other_process = Process(target=my_other_service.loops_forever)
my_other_process.start()
```

The problem with this solution is that the created object (OtherService) is not serializable and I get a "can't pickle _thread.lock object" error in the last line above.

How can I start a new process from my main class, and tell that process to create a new OtherService object (handing that process only the address parameter) and then tell that other process to call loops_forever?

Note that the solution doesnt have to use pythons multiprocessing, I will use whichever package makes most sense.

Comment: Please post the relevant code directly in this question. It's not very helpful for everyone to answer this question while most of the relevant code is in your linked question.

Comment: sorry @bnaecker. I added the code to the solution I tried

Comment: Please explain why you want to instantiate `my_other_service` in the main process and then call one of its methods in the other process.  Why not just instantiate in the other process and call its methods from there?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got the answer in your question, in English. You just have to translate it into code.

> tell that process to create a new OtherService object (handing that process only the address parameter) and then tell that other process to call loops_forever?

Create a simple new function, which will take an address, create an `OtherService` object, and call its `loops_forever()` method. *This* function is what's passed as the `target` of the new process you create.

Like so:

```
def create_service_and_loop(address):
    service = OtherService(address)
    service.loops_forever()

proc = multiprocessing.Process(target=create_service_and_loop, args=(ADDRESS,))
proc.start()
```

Comment: thanks @bnaecker! Didn't know it was that simple. Worked like a charm :)

Comment: You're welcome. In general, it's a good idea to keep objects entirely within one process or thread. It makes your life easier, and avoids many nasty synchronization problems. Good luck!